# Contour integral over a non-rectifiable contour

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

In chapter 16 of *Mathematical Analysis* Apostol defines contour integrals in terms of Riemann-Stieltjes integrals, specifically:

$$\int_\gamma f = \int_a^b f[\gamma(t)]\,d\gamma(t)$$
whenever the Riemann-Stieltjes integral on the right exists. My question would be "Find necessary and sufficient conditions on a contour $\gamma$ to ensure that the Riemann-Stieltjes integral defined above (and thus the contour integral) exists for all continuous complex functions $f$."

It is well-known that requiring $\gamma$ to be rectifiable is a sufficient condition for the contour integral to exist. But is it necessary? Is it the case that for every non-rectifiable curve $\gamma$ we can find a continuous function $f$ for which $\int_\gamma f$ (as defined above) does not exist? If it is not a necessary condition, what is?

Comment: If $f(x) = 1$ then for every tagged partition of the interval [a,b] the finite Riemann sum has the form $\sum_{i=1}^n(\gamma(x_i) - \gamma(x_{i-1}))$ which is a telescoping sum that collapses to $\gamma(x_n) - \gamma(x_0) = \gamma(b) - \gamma(a)$. Non-rectifiability only means that partitions can be found that make $\sum_{i=1}^n|\gamma(x_i) - \gamma(x_{i-1})|$ arbitrarily high.